# SQL Server group by alternative without losing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this which needs to be grouped by Name column but need to retain Ids and Dates
Is there a solution without `XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG`

```
Id  Name    Date    
1   Apple   2018/20/04  
2   Apple   2018/20/03  
3   Orange  2018/20/01  
4   Apple   2018/20/02  
5   Orange  2018/20/03
```

Group by name should yield =>

```
Id  Name    Date        Group
1   Apple   2018/20/04  1
2   Apple   2018/20/03  1
3   Orange  2018/20/01  2
4   Apple   2018/20/02  1
5   Orange  2018/20/03  2
```

Comment: You can use `DENSE_RANK()` or `RANK()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

Using `DENSE_RANK` function,then `ORDER BY ID` to keep the `order` is asc

```
SELECT Id,Name,Dates,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME) 'GROUP'
FROM T2
ORDER BY ID
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10652/1*

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Select [ID], [Name], [Date], 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [Name] order by [ID]) as [Group]
from TableName
```

Result

```
+----+----------+--------------+-------+
| ID | Name     |    Date      | Group |
+----+----------+--------------+-------+
|  1 | Apple    | 2018/20/04   |     1 |
|  2 | Apple    | 2018/20/03   |     2 |
|  4 | Apple    | 2018/20/02   |     3 |
|  3 | Orange   | 2018/20/01   |     1 |
|  5 | Orange   | 2018/20/03   |     2 |
+----+----------+--------------+-------+
```